# thymeleaf, bind model properties to multiple form elements

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a model property (region) than can be bound to more than one form elements as shown below:

```
<select th:field="*{region}" class="custom-select" id="country" style="padding: 0px">
     <option value="a" selected>Select one..</i></option>
     <option th:each="country : ${counties}" th:value="${country.id}" th:text="${country.name}"
      selected></option>
</select>

<select th:field="*{region}" class="custom-select" id="state" style="padding: 0px">
     <option value="a" selected>Select one..</i></option>
     <option th:each="state : ${states}" th:value="${state.id}" th:text="${state.name}"       
      selected></option>
</select>
```

as shown, region property of the model can be bound to either country or state and i have a radio group for user to select one of the two. My question is on how determine the one to pass to the controller to be saved. Is there a way to dynamically set the th:field for the model, or us there any other working solution?

Comment: Set the attribute `disabled="disabled"` on the one that you do not want sent to the controller, since disabled elements are not submitted (eg see https://html.com/attributes/input-disabled/ )

Comment: `Is there a way to dynamically set the th:field for the model`  No.  Thymeleaf (and so all the "th:" attributes) run on server at page-generation time, and so cannot respond to page runtime (on the browser) actions.

Comment: @racraman Thank you!